# What is the Main function of DefaultControllerFactory and GetControllerInstance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm learning MVC3 and im reading the book "pro asp.net MVC3 framework" I have read a few articles about DefaultControllerFactory and also on how to use ninject as de DI. DefaultControllerFactory  is creating a new controller that is going to use ninject right? would this means that this new controller would be called evertytime you call a new controller such as ProductController : Controller?

I read the articles below for ninject but its very basic. And the below example is more complex so if anybody can explain it a little bit it would help a lot! Thank you so much in Advance and I hope it helps others too.

[Step by Step Using Ninject for Dependency Injector](http://www.christiaanverwijs.nl/post/2012/07/28/A-step-by-step-guide-to-using-Ninject-for-dependancy-injection-in-C-sharp.aspx/%22A%20step-by-step%20guide%20to%20using%20Ninject%20for%20dependency%20injection%20in%20C#%22)

For DefaultControllerFactory:

[Controller lookup and default controller factory](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/controller_lookup_and_default_controller_factory/%22Controller%20lookup%20and%20default%20controller%20factory%22)

Product.cs

```
namespace SportsStore3.WebUI.Controllers
{
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductsRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductsRepository productRepository)
    {
        repository = productRepository;        
    }
}
```

Infrastructure.cs

```
namespace SportsStore3.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
public class Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {           
            ninjectKernel.Bind<SportsStore3.Domain.Abstract.IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();             
        }
    }
}
}
```

EFProductRepository.cs

```
namespace SportsStore3.WebUI.Concrete
{
public class EFProductRepository : IProductsRepository{
     private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products{
        get {return context.Products;}
    }           
}
}
```

IProductRespository.cs

```
namespace SportsStore3.Domain.Abstract
{
 public interface IProductsRepository
{
     IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
}
}
```

Products.cs

```
namespace SportsStore3.Domain
{
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SportsStore3.WebUI.Infrastructure.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory()); ;
    }
```

Comment: I would not bother, with the latest and future versions I assume, the framework uses `IDependencyResolver`, so such implementations and wiring are not needed anymore.

Comment: Things have changed a lot since MVC3, and while some people still prefer to override `DefaultControllerFactory`, most people use the built-in DI integration point of `IDependencyResolver` which does not require this to be done any longer.  On top of that, you don't need to do many of the things older Ninject articles say you have to do, such as deriving a new HttpApplication object.  While it's good to read this stuff, realize that it's way out of date and use it as a basis for your learning and go from there and find newer material.

Comment: Mxmissile and Erik than you so much for the answers i would find new articles on the new technology available. Erik when you use IDependecy Resolver that means that this would be youd DI or do you still need to use ninject even when using IDependencyResolver